# what does it mean to create a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Create a class named Participant with fields for a `name`, `age`, and `street address`. Include a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field and a `toString()` method that returns a String containing all the values. 
Also include an `equals()` method that determines two Participants are equal if they have the same values in all three fields.

Create an application with two arrays of at least 5 Participants each--one holds the Participants in the mini-marathon and the other holds Participants in the diving competition. Prompt the user for Participants who are in both events

- how to create a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field in java?
- how to assign parameter value

  ```
  public class BC {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String address;

  // I need help here. Please explain how to create a
  // constructor that assigns parameter values to each field
  public BC(String strName, int intAge, String strAddress) {
      name = strName;
      age = intAge;
      address = strAddress;
  }        
  }
  ```

Comment: `how to create a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field in java?` - besides the formatting and a dangling closing brace, what is wrong with the constructor shown in the code? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor **is** a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field. Your class `BC` has three fields (`name`, `age` and `address`). You assign values to all three fields in your constructor here

```
public BC(String strName, int intAge, String strAddress) {
    name = strName;
    age = intAge;
    address = strAddress;
}

                     }
```